# Set variable in controller that can be seen by directive

Tags: angularjs, variables, controller, scope, directive

I would like to pass some data from controller to directive, so directive first:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  'use strict';

  return {
    restrict: 'EA', 
    // templateUrl here
    controller: DataController,

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        var data = ctrl.data,

        config = {
          data: data,
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
          // ... more code here
        };
      //.. more  irrelevant code
   }
};
```

When I place the data like this, it works well :

```
nslive.controller('DataController', ['Data', 'socketio', '$routeParams', DataController]);

function DataController(Data, socketio, $routeParams) {
  'use strict';

  var vm = this;

  vm.data = [
    {y: '2014', a: 12500, b: 38000}, {y: '2015', a: 10500, b: 27000},
    {y: '2016', a: 38640, b: 13545}, {y: '2017', a: 38640, b: 13000}
  ];

  // more code here
}
```

However, when I place it inside the '.success()' callback function like this, the data can not be seen by the directive:

```
nslive.controller('DataController', ['Data', 'socketio', '$routeParams', DataController]);

function DataController(Data, socketio, $routeParams) {
  'use strict';

  var vm = this;
  vm.urlJobname = $routeParams.jobname;

  Data
    .all(vm.urlJobname)
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log('I got here!'); // this is shown successfully in the chrome console
      vm.data = [
        {y: '2014', a: 12500, b: 38000}, {y: '2015', a: 10500, b: 27000},
        {y: '2016', a: 38640, b: 13545}, {y: '2017', a: 38640, b: 13000}
      ];
    });
}
```

I think it has something to do with the variable scope, but do not know how to set such a global variable, please advise. Thanks.

Comment: you can pass `$scope` to directive. or use `scope: {<some variables>}` in directive and populate particular variables in any `controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because the directive is compiled and the ink function is executed before the promise/request returns the success message ,,
so it will be compiled ,, I suggest wrapping your logic inside a $watch and clear that watch after executing it for the first time

so this will be your link function

```
function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
   scope.clearWatch = scope.$watch(function(){return ctrl.data;},function(newVal){
       if(newVal){
          //your logic goes here ,, we are sure that ctrl.data has value here
         // here we call clearWatch to stop watching on that value
         scope.clearWatch();
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: It really works. Thanks a lot. btw, you missed parentheses, haha@Ahmed Eid

Comment: get a question about $watch function, why the first param should be a function (return ctrl.data) but not 'ctrl.data' directly?@Ahmed Eid

Comment: haha :D :D I fixed it :)
regarding  the watchExpression ,, follow this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope ,, and search for "watchExpression" , it accepts only strings and functions

Answer (score 0):

In directive:

```
scope: {
          object: '='
       }
```

Best practice is to have a `Controller` for Directive instead putting it in `link` function.

In Controller directive:

```
$scope.$watch('object', function (){
      // do something with data
});
```

In HTML:

```
<my-directive object=objectFromController></my-directive>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.objectFromController = data;
```

Comment: yeah, makes sense. let me try.@maddog

Comment: question, adding $watch func in controller directive, what is controller directive, is it the controller in .directive definition? or in my seperate controller file? thank you. @maddog

Comment: you can define `controller` in directive. and then you can define in separate file or in the same one. you can refer:http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers

Comment: yeah, done, it works as well. Thank you very much, I learned.@maddog